# In kbase database, is there "!=" operator?

Tags: database

***In kbase database, is there "!=" operator or some syntax can be used as "!="?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kbase database, there is not "!=" usage, but can use "not" instead of "!=";

```
For example: select * from tableName where feildName1= value1 not feildName2=value2
```